# algolia search security on the client side

Tags: security, algolia, api-key

I am using algolia search for a prototype and trying to figure out how to have security implemented (only users with account, can have ability to update/create and index)
Application has no back end and uses firebase and firestore only
I am planning to implement google authentication in it
Now the question is how to implement security for algolia without the back end
I have read in algolia documentation that API keys can be generated for users, but then how to make sure they don't leak and how to generate them automatically when users login for example
I have limited knowledge related to cryptography, API keys and handshakes so i do not have any clear view of how this should be done without back-end
Anyone came across similar issues and/or ways to tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

Always use "Search-Only API Key" for the client side. And for security, you can generate new "Search-Only API Key" and kill the old keys ( you can automate this key generation using the Admin Key)

Answer (score 2):

We recommend to use Search-Only API Keys for keys that are gonna be exposed on front end side.

However, if you need to provide user-specific keys to let your own users interact with your Algolia indices, you could probably benefit from our Secured API Keys that can be generated on-demand via the backend (not sure it could fit with your use case though). Here is the official documentation for this feature: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys/#secured-api-keys.

Comment: Ok i guess there is no way around having some logic on Node
Thank You this clears things up